# check uncategorized category by default

Tags: plugins, posts, categories

I would like to check the category 'uncategorized' by default when user creates a new post. Any idea how to go about it?

The default setting is 'Uncategorized' in **Settings > Writing**
[image]

However, it is still uncheck here when I want to create a new post:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I want **Uncategorized** to be chosen by default. This is a clean WP install.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be checked to work. When you publish the post, as long as you haven't added another category and explicitly checked it, WordPress will automatically assign the Uncategorized category for you. Once you hit publish and the page refreshes you'll see the checkbox checked.

Comment: Thank You. Didn't know that. I am actually asking since my production version of Wordpress has a hook that requires to have the category checked by default else the hook throws an error. Perhaps, I'll look for a javascript solution.